# Why is SFTP so slow on Azure VM

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-networking

I have a VM on Azure, with an SFTP server installed (from nsoftware).

I know SFTP is slower than FTP, but the speed I am getting is abysmal:

Upload: File transfer successful, transferred 10,485,760 bytes in 19 seconds

Download: File transfer successful, transferred 10,485,760 bytes in 99 seconds

The Upload I could live with, but 99 seconds for a 10MB file is unacceptable.

I have tried ramping up the Memory and CPU to very high levels, but the speeds remain unchanged.  So it is not clear to me what is throttling the download.

I have check the Performance Monitor, and both CPU and Bandwidth appears ok on both the client and the server.

I don't know what else to try here to speed up the download speed.

SFTP is required by the Trading Partner, so I cannot switch protocols.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up switching to a Linux VM that was specifically meant for SFTP and the speed was dramatically better.